# Dojo layout, position absolute

Tags: html, css, layout, dojo, alfresco

I'm want use the dojo library for my Alfresco page, so I decide to use dojo layouts. I decide to wrap all page in dojo layout. I use 'region: top' for my header part of page, but there is a problem with viewing popups because dojo top layout has style "position: absolute" and Alfresco popups have too.

I can set style "position: static" for header part and will be ok, but I think it non my way.

```
<@templateBody>
  <div id="fullPage" class="claro" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/LayoutContainer">
  <div id="alf-hd" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region: 'top'">
    <@region id="header" scope="global"/>
    <@region id="title" scope="page"/>
  </div>
  <div id="bd" class="claro" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region: 'center'">
    <@region id="column" scope="page"/>
  </div>
</div>
</@>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't delved into Alfresco much to be honest, but can you not set the z-index properties of your dojo header and alfresco popups so that they overlay correctly?

Or am I missing the point?!